# npm node_modules command not found on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I've got a problem starting npm modules f.e. ionic, cordova, protractor. When I write something f.e.like:

```
ionic serve
```

It response with:

```
zsh: command not found: ionic
```

I installed these modules globally `npm install -g ionic` and locally `npm install ionic`, but the output is still the same. Also I tried to run them locally in directory ./node_modules/.bin/ again the same result. Another thing, that I've tried to change path of installation like here [Cannot run ionic. receives "No command 'ionic' found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127738/cannot-run-ionic-receives-no-command-ionic-found), but didn't get the needed result. I still think, that the reason is in path, that npm installs modules, in my case it's ~/npm/bin. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using bash and running the same command.

Comment: Ok, I started to believe in magic. Why it's working in bash and don't work in normal shell?

Comment: Probably ionic bin file is in the bash lookup directories but not in the normal shell. It may be related to how NPM setup was done in your machine.