# Cannot use ionic or cordova

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm

i installed ionic on mu Ubuntu using this:

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

i know i was tested that via ionic command and it was working.
but now when i try to run it using `ionic` i see this :

```
No command 'ionic' found
```

i tried this but that wasnt my problem.
[Cannot run ionic. receives "No command 'ionic' found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127738/cannot-run-ionic-receives-no-command-ionic-foundw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo ln -s /home/guy/npm/bin/ionic /usr/bin/ionic
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`sudo npm install -g ionic`
then type the code
`ionic -v` to check the version of ionic.
If you are able to see the ionic version, your ionic is installed.